# How to launch Line Messenger app through HTML href attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Help me to open **Line app** from href. 
for example we can open WhatsApp from url scheme like below

href="**whatsapp**://send?text=abcdefg"

Comment: https://media.line.me/en/#lineitbutton ?

Comment: If you are talking about the Windows OS, then you need to create a protocol in the registry (just like http://, or whatsapp://) and tell windows which application to trigger when URL with such protocol is clicked on in the browser.

Comment: thanks @Ahs N , but here im opening that with android os. Android Mobile Browser

Comment: thanks @lxe its helps and solved my query :)